# Place link inside Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a code found on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/fNyHs/ since it seems to be the best for my situation as where I need dynamical text to fit the container (by changing the font size).

```
(function($) {
$.fn.textfill = function(maxFontSize, maxWords) {
    maxFontSize = parseInt(maxFontSize, 10);
    maxWords = parseInt(maxWords, 10) || 4;
    return this.each(function(){
        var self = $(this),
            orgText = self.text(),
            fontSize = parseInt(self.css("fontSize"), 10),
            lineHeight = parseInt(self.css("lineHeight"), 10),
            maxHeight = self.height(),
            maxWidth = self.width(),
            words = self.text().split(" ");

        function calcSize(text) {
            var ourText = $("<span class='dyntextval'><a href='#' class='trigger'>"+text+"</a></span>").appendTo(self),
                multiplier = maxWidth/ourText.width(),
                newSize = fontSize*(multiplier-0.1);
            ourText.css(
                "fontSize", 
                (maxFontSize > 0 && newSize > maxFontSize) ? 
                    maxFontSize : 
                    newSize
            );
            var scrollHeight = self[0].scrollHeight;
            if (scrollHeight  > maxHeight) {
                multiplier = maxHeight/scrollHeight;
                newSize = (newSize*multiplier);
                ourText.css(
                    "fontSize", 
                    (maxFontSize > 0 && newSize > maxFontSize) ? 
                        maxFontSize : 
                        newSize
                );
            }
        }
        self.empty();
        if (words.length > maxWords) {
            while (words.length > 0) {
                var newText = words.splice(0, maxWords).join(" ");
                console.log
                calcSize(newText);
                self.append("<br>");
            }
        } else {
            calcSize(orgText);
        }
    });
};
})(jQuery);



$(document).ready(function() {
$('.large').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 120, minFontPixels: 36});
$('.medium').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 32 });
$('.small').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 18 });        
});
```

But I am having a problem with this part:

```
var ourText = $(""+text+"").appendTo(self),
```

The thing is that I need a link inside there which toggles another div once clicked.

**The toggle:**

```
$(".side-toggle").hide();
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.group').find('.side-toggle').slideToggle();
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});

$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".group").slideToggle();
});
```

The toggle works by itself, but not when I also implement the code text fill code.

**The html:**

```
<div class="quepasa">
  <div class="large artist">
    <span class="dyntextval">
      <a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="#" class="trigger">
        <?php if ( get_the_title() ) the_title(); else the_ID(); ?>+
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't have enough jQuery knowledge to know how:
a) to put the link in?
b) Keep the toggle function

I hope someone out there can help me out.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of how it works without textfill code?

Comment: I couldn't connect the dots b/w what you have posted and what you want to achieve. Can you post the complete code of what you attempted to merge?

Comment: I am trying to achieve:
1. Text fill > the font size decreases/increases to fill the container. I was using jQuery textfill (http://www.geekymonkey.com/programming/jquery/TextFill/example.htm)  for that, but some words would go outside the container, so I ended up with the above code that seems to help keep the text within the container.
2. Using the above code, I would like to put the link back in. This piece
    `var ourText = $("<span>+text+"</span>").appendTo(self)`
removed the url.

Comment: Right now I am trying to work it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/inTOWN/vxSze/2/

Comment: @Vega : I posted a working one here: http://jsfiddle.net/inTOWN/vxSze/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by moving the toggle trigger to a div surrounding the link:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="group">
<div class="large trigger"><a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="#" class="large"><?php if ( get_the_title() ) the_title(); else the_ID(); ?>+</a></div>
<div class="side-toggle">Content of the toggle</div>
```

**Toggle script:**

```
$(".side-toggle").hide(); 
$('.trigger').click(function() {
$(this).closest('.group').find('.side-toggle').slideToggle();
return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

**Textfill script:**

```
(function($) {
$.fn.textfill = function(maxFontSize, maxWords) {
    maxFontSize = parseInt(maxFontSize, 10);
    maxWords = parseInt(maxWords, 10) || 4;
    return this.each(function(){
        var self = $(this),
            orgText = self.text(),
            fontSize = parseInt(self.css("fontSize"), 10),
            lineHeight = parseInt(self.css("lineHeight"), 10),
            maxHeight = self.height(),
            maxWidth = self.width(),
            words = self.text().split(" ");

        function calcSize(text) {
            var ourText = $("<span>"+text+"</span>").appendTo(self),
                multiplier = maxWidth/ourText.width(),
                newSize = fontSize*(multiplier-0.1);
            ourText.css(
                "fontSize", 
                (maxFontSize > 0 && newSize > maxFontSize) ? 
                    maxFontSize : 
                    newSize
            );
            var scrollHeight = self[0].scrollHeight;
            if (scrollHeight  > maxHeight) {
                multiplier = maxHeight/scrollHeight;
                newSize = (newSize*multiplier);
                ourText.css(
                    "fontSize", 
                    (maxFontSize > 0 && newSize > maxFontSize) ? 
                        maxFontSize : 
                        newSize
                );
            }
        }
        self.empty();
        if (words.length > maxWords) {
            while (words.length > 0) {
                var newText = words.splice(0, maxWords).join(" ");
                console.log
                calcSize(newText);
                self.append("<br>");
            }
        } else {
            calcSize(orgText);
        }
    });
};
})(jQuery);



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.large').textfill(120, 42);
  $('.medium').textfill(90,24);
  $('.small').textfill(24,18);
});
```

The CSS:

```
.large, .medium, .small {text-align: center;white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden;word-wrap: break-word;width:526px; max-width:526px; }
.large{line-height:180px;}
.medium {letter-spacing:2px; line-height:72px;}
.small {letter-spacing:2px; line-height:18px;}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/inTOWN/vxSze/10/

Only wish I knew how to spread the text more, so it would fill the whole container

Answer (score 0):

What's happening with your toggle is a break in the Javascript stack, or simply, an error early on makes everything else go to hell.

Example:

Let's say this causes an error (cannot call `bar` on `undefined`)

`var darth = $('#foo').data().bar;`

Then in this block of Code:

```
$('#threepeeoh').hide();
var darth = $('#foo').data().bar;
$('luke').show('fade', 500);
```

`#luke` will never show because there was an error on the line before. `#threepeeoh` was able to hide because he did so before `darth` showed up and threw an error. And any code that happens after that will most likely not be executed. (It's worth Googling " JS try/catch blocks")

So, when you add your textfill code, it must be throwing an error and making it *seem* like your toggle is FUBAR.

As far as what that error is, you need to learn to use a Javascript Debugger for your web browser and see what error is thrown. As far as I can tell, `var ourText = $(""+text+"").appendTo(self)` isn't even in the code block you posted, nor the fiddle, so I don't even know what you're talking about.

So:

1. Go find a Developer Console to use a Javascript Debugger with (Firefug is popular, Chrome has one built in, hit CTRL SHIFT J)
2. Refresh, the look for the error (most likely in red)
3. Edit your question (might be better to ask a new one) and post that error WITH the code near where the error was thrown ( a file and line number is usually provided )
4. If possible, upload a sample of your work to a public server that you don't plan to delete, so the community can reference it.

Comment: Hey Kyle, Thanks for the comments. The toggle wasn't breaking though. The output of the textfill just didn't didn't give the link (and therefor no toggle).

I solved it though: http://jsfiddle.net/inTOWN/vxSze/10/